# vector in 2D real space

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I'm getting confused about the dimension and space of vector. is this matrix in $\Bbb R^2$ or is it in $\Bbb R^{2 \times 4}$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\3 & 4 & 5 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: It is very unclear what you have asked. Can you reformulate your question?

Comment: Perhaps it's a part of a cycle in $S_6$, namely $(123456)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matrix is indeed in $\Bbb R^{2 \times 4}$. First thing to notice: every matrix of size $m \times n$, elements of $\Bbb K^{m \times n}$, where $m$ is the number of rows and $n$ the number of columns, can represent a (finite dimensional) linear map from $\Bbb K^n \to \Bbb K^m$ (where $\Bbb K$ is the scalar field from which the matrix coefficients are taken).

The number of coefficients in a vector ($a fortiori$, matrix, since matrix spaces are vector spaces) is the overall dimension of that vector. Here, $2 \times 4 = 8$, and there are indeed 8 coefficients in your matrix. There is thus of course an isomorphism $\Bbb R^{2 \times 4} \simeq \Bbb R^{8}$.

Answer (score 0):

This matrix is an element of $\mathbb R^{2\times 4}$. It acts on vectors from $\mathbb R^2$ outputting vectors from $\mathbb R^4$.

Answer (score 0):

This matrix represents a linear application from $\mathbb{R}^4$ To $\mathbb{R}^2$ if you want to see it like a vector it is in $M_{2*4}(\mathbb{R})$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2*4}$ that Is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^8$